# Pass data to module in Vuex on load

Tags: vuex, vuex-modules

I have a reusable Vuex module for CRUD methods to an API. How can I pass the relevant URL from the parent module when loading?
e.g.

`company.module.js`

```
var URL;
const state = {
   all: [],
   items: [],
   editing: false,
   url: URL
};
...
export default {
   state,
   getters,
   actions,
   mutations,
   modules: {
     crud: crudModule
   }
};
```

`crud.module.js`

```
const state = {
    url: '', // Get the URL from company.module here?
    status: {
        loading: false,
        success: false,
        error  : false
    }
};
...
const actions = {
     async fetchItems(context, data ) {
         commit('QUERY_REQUEST');
         var url = '';// Or get the URL from parent state?
         return axios.get( url )
             .then( response => {
                 ...
             });
     },
}
...
export default {
     namespaced: true,
     modules: {
         meta: metaModule
     },
     state: () => state,
     getters,
     mutations,
     actions
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of a module, I put the crud state, getters, mutations and actions into a class with the endpoint as a parameter. I can then use the `Crud` class in each of my namespaced modules and merge it using the spread operator.

`crud.js`

```
export default class {
    constructor ( endpoint ) {
       this.state = {
          url: endpoint,
          status: {
            loading: false,
            success: false,
            error  : false
          }
       };

        this.getters = getters;
        this.mutations = mutations;
        this.actions = actions;
    }
}

const getters = {
  //...
};
const actions = {
  //...
};
const mutations = {
  //...
};
```

`company.module.js`

```
import Crud from './api/crud';
let endpoint = "/api/companies";

var crud = new Crud( endpoint );

const state = {
    ...crud.state
};

const getters = {
    ...crud.getters  
};

const actions = {
    ...crud.actions
};

const mutations = {
    ...crud.mutations
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this is going to work.

```
 async fetchItems({commit, rootGetters }, data ) {
     commit('QUERY_REQUEST');
     let url = rootGetters['company/url']
 }
```

link to official docs: [accessing-global-assets-in-namespaced-modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#accessing-global-assets-in-namespaced-modules)

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. The problem I had is that `crud.module.js` is reusable. I wouldn't know the 'company' namespace.

Comment: yeah, makes sense(